# Weak Supervision - training generative model without knowing the true label

Tags: machine-learning, conditional-probability, generative-models, semi-supervised-learning

Recently I've been reading about [weak supervision](http://ai.stanford.edu/blog/weak-supervision/). I understand most of the concept details, there's one thing that is not clear to me though.

In the generative model part (creating generative model from labeling function, the **Generative Model as an Expressive Vehicle** section) there's a statement:

> By learning a generative model, and directly estimating P(L|y), we are essentially learning the relative accuracies of the labeling functions based on how they overlap and conflict (note, we don’t need to know y!)

How is estimating `P(L|y)` without knowing `y` possible? Is this due to some assumption w.r.t. weak supervision that I didn't catch or is this related to some conditional probability property I'm not able to apply here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems the word *note* in the statement quoted didn't actually mean something obvious. Anyway, the answer is in the paper in the 2.2 Generative Model chapter.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.10160.pdf